# Eclipse tomcat doesn't deploy web applications automatically

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

Hello all: We have done all of the eclipse server configuration (adding tomcat-juli.jar by using eclipse server configuration ) . and we spent two days searching in the internet and testing different version of tomcat and different pc , after that we realized that eclipse can’t deploy web application to tomcat service automatically , finally one thread of stackoverflow suggest to build the war manually by right clicking on the project and choosing Export -> war file  , as you know it is not the solution . I would much appreciate if you suggest any solution

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to install Tomcat separately and build your WAR file with an ANT script, which will automatically deploy your War file to `$TOMCAT_HOME/webapps`. In `$TOMCAT_HOME/conf/server.xml`, make sure you have `unpackWARs` and `autoDeploy` set to `"true"`:

```
<Host name="localhost"  
  appBase="webapps"
  unpackWARs="true" 
  autoDeploy="true">
```